# I'm a beginner in Android web view development. What should I do to keep the cookies?

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-webview

I'm a beginner in Android web view development. What should I do to keep the cookies?
I would like to implement the php homepage using Android WebView. Most of the features have been implemented, but I don't know what to do with cookies that store id and pw
How should I implement it in what areas? Please teach me.

in this my mainactivity.java code

```
package com.example.webviewexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String url = "http://www.test.com/user/login.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

    }

    @Override

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.getUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.test.com/index.php") || webView.getUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.test.com/user/login.php")) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("exit")
                    .setMessage("exit?")
                    .setPositiveButton("finish", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                            moveTaskToBack(true);
                            finish();
                            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("no",null)
                    .show();

        }else if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private class WebViewClientClass extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep cookies, you can use below:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
```

You can extract all cookies from current url by this way from Webview as string:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
    Log.d(TAG, "All the cookies in a string:" + cookies);
}
```

Comment: quit the app, it will not be saved.

Comment: I Solve it. Thanks. It helped.
The next code fell out, so I added it and it worked.
CookieManager.getInstance().flush();